# Extract content of Span tag in python

Tags: python

I want to extract **1 Pack, 4 Pack Gift Set, 1 Pencil with erasers ,...**  from

```
[<span class="a-size-base">1 Pack</span>, <span class="a-size-base">4 Pack Gift Set</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Erasers</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers</span>]
```

in python.

Thanks

Comment: If you want an answer you'll have to provide a question. :)

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Beautiful Soup, the *de facto* Python library for parsing HTML. Get it [by downloading the source here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4) or with `pip install bs4`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '[<span class="a-size-base">1 Pack</span>, <span class="a-size-base">4 Pack Gift Set</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Erasers</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers</span>]'

# Represent the string as a nested data structure
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "html.parser")
# Find all <span> tags in the BeautifulSoup object
spans = soup.find_all('span')
# Get the text inside the <span> tags
print([span.text for span in spans])
```

This will get you a list of what you want:

```
['1 Pack', '4 Pack Gift Set', '1 Pencil with Erasers', '1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard library re(Regular expression operations).

```
import re

tag = '<span class="a-size-base">1 Pack</span>, <span class="a-size-base">4 Pack Gift Set</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Erasers</span>, <span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers</span>'

cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', tag)
print cleantext
```

the output is : 1 Pack, 4 Pack Gift Set, 1 Pencil with Erasers, 1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers

Answer (score 0):

Can you detail your question and data structure? assume your data structure is list of string:

```
import re
l = ['<span class="a-size-base">1 Pack</span>', '<span class="a-size-base">4 Pack Gift Set</span>', '<span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Erasers</span>', '<span class="a-size-base">1 Pencil with Lead and Erasers</span>']
print([re.match(r'<([a-zA-Z]+).+>(.+)</\1>', i).group(2) for i in l])
```